# uid = 10 for wheel group but do not see that id in /etc/passwd

Tags: centos

CentOS 7:

```
$ cat /etc/group 

wheel:x:10:a,b
```

However I do not see any user with gid=10 when I do

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

Is this some special id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is telling you that users `a` and `b` are members of the `wheel` group.

These are secondary memberships; the primary group is listed in `/etc/passwd` as part of the user record.

In this particular situation, where `wheel` is a group that confers special treatment, it's unlikely there will be any user with it as their primary group. So you shouldn't expect to find group 10 in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: If you could put this in the answer instead of the comment, please.

Answer (score 2):

> uid = 10 for wheel group

Incorrect.  That number 10 is the *group* ID of the `wheel` group.  It is not a *user* ID at all.  There's no reason to think that a user ID of 10 is relevant to that record in the groups table.  Certainly the number 10 in the *group ID field* does not indicate that.  There is no mandatory correspondence between user IDs and group IDs.  Groups are linked to users by their account names, as you can see, and by the primary group ID in the password table.

Comment: Yes, I mistakenly typed uid instead of gid as a comment earlier.

Answer (score 1):

There are not necessarily a user and group of the same name although that often happens (`root`, `nobody`).